# How to adjust font-size and reflow text to fit the width and height of a parent div with html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this example which is working: http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/1064/

But I wan't this to work with html tags also. For example, in the fiddle our text is wrapped in a div.

```
<div id="fitin">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

But I want this example to work with html tags as well:

```
<div id="fitin">
<div><h1>Lorem</h1> <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </p> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: But your code uses font which overrides the header's font size. Try using a base font size on the `fitin` div and set the child elements font-size using em

Comment: What do you mean by "it has to work with html tags" ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**viewport percentage units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) that vary the size according to the container's size:

> **vh**
>   1/100th of the height of the viewport.
>   **vw**
>   1/100th of the width of the viewport.
>   **vmin**
>   1/100th of the minimum value between the height and the width of the viewport.
>   **vmax**
>   1/100th of the maximum value between the height and the width of the viewport.

This way, you don't let javascript handle a visual issue (which is heavy to set `onresize` events), and you can use in any element.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/1064/

Comment: I'm confused by your fiddle, could you explain what's happening? I'm still stuck.

Comment: You don't need Javascript to detect the text and change the font-size... The `vmin` (or the others I described), already fits the container at the percentage value that you specified... Then, all the html tags will resize as well...

Comment: Oh,I see what you're saying.  But if the text is too large, it will overflow the div and not shrink inside.  http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/2667/